# HTC One VX - Rooted and I can't remove bloatware!

Tags: htc, titanium-backup, bloatware

My Note 2 was stolen during a mugging recently and I'm using an HTC One VX (ATT) until I can afford to get a better phone; insurance wasn't much help. The problem I'm having is that I unlocked the bootloader and rooted it (even though it's a temporary phone, it's slow as heck and I wanted to remove all the AT&T bloatware. I've used Titanium and ROM Toolbox Lite to delete those apps, but they keep coming back after a reboot. What can I do short of installing a custom rom (I don't want a custom rom on here unless absolutely necessary)? Or is there a "checker" system app that checks for and reinstalls these apps that I should freeze or remove? I'm open to experimentation and wouldn't mind "too" much if I accidently bricked it, I feel like taking a brick to this phone anyway, lol. This phone has Android 4.0.4.

TL;DR, rooted stock rom HTC One VX, trying to remove bloatware with Titanium and ROM Toolbox but bloatware comes back on reboot.

Comment: Can you check where that bloatware resides? Is the `.apk` installed in `/system/apps`, or rather `/data/apps`? I would wonder if it returned to `/system/apps` (as that's usually read-only), but could imagine a "fancy installer". Might help to pick up the log right after boot (`adb logcat` / `adb dmesg`) to follow the "initialization process".

Comment: The apk files are in /system/apps. Should I attempt to delete them first and then try the uninstall using Titanium? I'm concerned that this semi-imaginary checker might cause problems if it can't find the apks to reinstall when it checks for them, if you know what I mean.

Comment: If you uninstall them using TiBu, check the very same location *before* you reboot, to see whether the `.apk` files are really removed. But I guess the more important part is to check the logs, which hopefully contain hints on why the app comes back (and who does that).

Answer (score 0):

Stumble across this in a quest ordained to you by the mighty oracle of el goog?

I had the same problem as OP described. After installing a custom recovery and rooting my HTC Desire 610, I began removing bloatware, only to find it reinstalled when I rebooted.

Using Link2SD, you can view where the .apk files are in the system partition, such as /system/app/ATT_I_EAT_UR_SPACE. I removed them as well as the accompanying .odex files after removing them via Link2SD via the file manager in TWRP and it worked.

I'm no android guru, but it seemed to work, so good luck fellow traveller and may el goog grant you answers more easily in the future.